# How to hide an external drive from file sharing on local network

Tags: network, file-sharing, privacy

The problem is, my office has multiple computers, and there is only one account (admin) on every machine, all with the same password. So if I bring a personal firewire drive and attach it to my machine, everyone on the network can access it. What I need is a way to STOP file sharing for this external drive without adjusting permissions, because there is only one set of permissions for this computer, and everyone on the network has access to that account.

Answer (score 1):

The only way a drive would have it's sharing enabled is through the Sharing menu in system preferences.
Access the File Sharing menu inside there and remove your drive from the list.

That's the only thing I can come up with besides changing the drive permissions.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I think my problem is explained by this message in the Sharing preferences pane: "Other users can access shared folders on this computer, and administrators all volumes..." SO admins can see all volumes. My shared folders list is actually empty. I need some unix line or something will just not broadcast that drive to the network, even if a network user has admin access

Comment: I'm shooting blind here but what would happen if you were to right-click the drive, click on get info and scroll to the bottom and change permissions there?

Comment: Same problem. Admin user acct. still has Read & Write.

Comment: Well my last option is a desperate option that may or may not work as I haven't tried this myself. Unmount the drive using disk utility and see if there is a program out there that can read from an unmounted drive. I don't know if it's possible or not but if it's not avaliable to network sharing due to it being unmounted then it shouldn't appear but the question is can another piece of software still read/write to it if it's unmounted. Maybe it's something worth looking into if you're completely out of ideas.

Comment: OKAY here's my solution: TrueCrypt. I'm just encrypting all the stuff I don't want my coworkers to be able to see.